# elevate a child list to parent with lodash

Tags: lodash

I'm trying to wrap my head around lodash right now and wanted to figure out how to handle this particular situation with it rather than writing a foreach loop.

The object has the structure of activities and tasks.  An ActivityList has many activities.  Each activity has simple properties and a array of Tasks.  Each array of tasks has simple properties.  I want to generate a table that lists all the tasks from all the activities WITH some activity properties.

For example:

```
{
"Activities": [{
    "Name": "Activity1",
    "Tasks": [{
        "Name": "Task1",
        "Complete": "90%"
    }, {
        "Name": "Task2",
        "Complete": "40%"
    }, {
        "Name": "Task3",
        "Complete": "97%"
    }]
}, {
    "Name": "Activity2",
    "Tasks": [{
        "Name": "Task4",
        "Complete": "100%"
    }, {
        "Name": "Task5",
        "Complete": "25%"
    }, {
        "Name": "Task6",
        "Complete": "17%"
    }]
}]
}
```

I would like this to come up as

```
    Activity1 Task1 90%
    Activity1 Task2 40%
    Activity1 Task3 97%
    Activity2 Task4 100%
```

I think I'm getting the hang of using the basic commands individually, but I'm missing something when it comes to chaining them together.  I think this needs some combination of map, flattendeep, and pluck but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: maybe there are better tags I can use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
var data = { ... }; // your object with the activities array

var result = _.flatMap(data.Activities, function (activity) { 
    return _.map(activity.Tasks, function (task) { 
        return { activity: activity.Name, task: task.Name, complete: task.Complete };
    });
});
```

Then the result would resolve to an array of objects:

```
 [
    {"activity":"Activity1","task":"Task1","complete":"90%"},
    {"activity":"Activity1","task":"Task2","complete":"40%"},
    {"activity":"Activity1","task":"Task3","complete":"97%"},
    {"activity":"Activity2","task":"Task4","complete":"100%"},
    {"activity":"Activity2","task":"Task5","complete":"25%"},
    {"activity":"Activity2","task":"Task6","complete":"17%"}
]
```

And you can loop through the items to create your table.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed.  Thanks!  Out of curiosity, what exactly does flatten do?  Does it just create an enumeration to iterate over?  Essentially, just doing a for loop while returning the indexed item in the collection?

Comment: The `_.map` function returns an array (to `_.flatMap`) of objects per task and includes the activity name. The `_.flatMap` combines these returned arrays to a flattened result.